# JavaScript array[] values are the same as the last added value

Tags: javascript, jstl

the alert within the forEach prints the values as they are inserted , but after the forEach all the values in the array are the same. Assume I have 3 values successfully insererted . I have a global array[] somewhere up in the code , I tried change it within the function , but same result , JSTL making a a problem mayb?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
var jokeArray = [];

                   function ALL(){
                     var object = new Object;
                     var x = new String();
                      <c:forEach var="joke" items="${jokeAllList}">
                           x = '${joke.content}';
                           x = x.replace(/{/g,"\n");
                           x = x.replace(/}/g,"\r"); 
                           object.content = x;
                           object.category = '${joke.category}';
                           object.rate = '${joke.rate}';
                           object.postby = '${joke.postby}';
                           object.votes = '${joke.votes}';
                           object.image = '${joke.image}';
                           jokeArray.unshift(object);
                           alert(jokeArray[0].content);
                      </c:forEach>

why index(s) 0 & 1 & 2 have the same VALUES ? ( Assume there are values and jokeArray.length = 3 )

              alert ( "arr length is " + jokeArray.length);
              alert(jokeArray[0].content);
              alert(jokeArray[1].content);
              alert(jokeArray[2].content);
              alert("done ALL method");
```

};

```
alert("done ALL method");
```

is alerted , so no errors

Comment: Tip: Don't use the String constructor, `typeof new String === "object"` and that may cause problems further along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that because `var object = new Object;` and `var x = new String()` are outside the loop, you only have a single object for each which is having its contents overwritten on subsequent iterations of the loop (even though the object has been added to the array it can still be changed).

Try moving those two lines into the loop. You'll still have a single `object` JavaScript variable (because of the way JS doesn't really support scope-level variables) but you will have a different object for each iteration.

Comment: WORKED! Thanks for the fast reply !

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the "object" variable, please do

```
object = new Object();
```

inside your loop!